# SQL Group By within some time frame

Tags: sql

I need to group by id, status within some timestamp.

for example I have this table:

```
id    | status | time   | value | deviceId
1     |  true  | 10:31  |   1   |      5 
2     |  true  | 10:32  |   2   |     5 
3     |  true  | 10:33  |   3   |     5
4     |  false | 10:34  |   3   |    5 
5     |  false | 10:35  |   4   |   5 
6     |  false | 10:36  |   5   |    5 
7     |  true  | 10:37  |   4   |    5
8     |  true  | 10:38  |   5   |    5
9     |  true  | 10:39  |   6   |  5
```

Table is ordered by time.

Every group should be for same id, if status is true, within time were status is true.

For same groupId I will need new results when status become true, but this is in another time frame so should be another group.

Based on above example result should be:

```
deviceId  | avg(value)
5 | 2 (average value for rows 1,2,3 for deviceid = 5)
5 | 5       (average value of rows 7,8,9 for deviceid = 5. Same group, but another time frame)
```

I can group by deviceId and group by  status.

```
SELECT  deviceid ,status, AVG(value)
FROM mytable
WHERE status = true
GROUP BY deviceid,status;
```

But I don't know how to do all that within time frame?
Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

I tried to explain what is time frame. Maybe my English is not good enough so I will try again. You can see that time is in order. Table is ordered by time.

Rows 1,2,3 are within time frame while status i true.

In row 4 status is false so this is time when second time frame starts.
Second time frame are rows 4,5,6.

In row 7 status is again true, so here third time frame starts. Third time frame are rows 7,8,9

I just need results of groups where status is true, so only first and third time frame are relevant to me.

Comment: 1,2,3 and 7,8,9 are rows, not columns. Also, please define what a timeframe is to you. I just see a bunch of different times, and I don't see how some of them belong together and others don't.

Comment: What is the type of the time column?

Comment: @majidarif Timestamp

Comment: Time cannot be hardcoded. It should work for any time frame. I could have 1000 time frames.

Comment: SQL is just a language, what rdbms are you working with? Please [edit] your question to include the rdbms product tag as well as the specific version tag.

Comment: Well, what is a timeframe?

Comment: Seeing as Timeframe is not defined, it's not really possible to give a specific answer, but you'll likely end up having to do some subqueries which transforms your Time into a singular value you then can group upon, using some of the other tools. But "Timeframe" is the important aspect for such a question.

Comment: I edited question, I hope that you can understand now.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: "*Table is ordered by time*" **no** it is not. Rows in a table are not "sorted" in any way.

Comment: They are sorted in third column. Column name is 'time'. Type should be timestamp, but I just wrote short version in hours and minutes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name At the end I will need to write this is Java Spark and save to Kafka topic. But for know I would just like to know how to write this in pure sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the groups of "true"s by doing a cumulative count of "false"s.  This count will be constant for a group of consecutive "true"s.

The rest is then just filtering and aggregation:

```
select deviceid, grp, avg(value)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceid order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'true'
group by deviceid, grp;
```